# Is there a difference between the definition of the group $L_{n}(R)$ and that of $GL_{n}(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Is there a difference between the definition of the group $L_{n}(R)$ and that of $GL_{n}(R)$?

I already know the definition of $GL_{n}(R)$.

Comment: what is your definition of $L_n(\mathbb{R})$, seems like you are not talking about the lebesque space.

Comment: I am asking about its definition @Enkidu I have searched about it but did not find it.

Comment: I am quite versatile with linear algebra, but to my knowledge there is no standard concept in linear algebra which is denoted like that. So I can't tell you about the difference without you giving me at least a name for it.

Comment: This was a notation written in the book "Linear representations of groups " by Vinberg ..... we are studying representation theory ..... I just added linear algebra tag because I know that the other group is defined in linear algebra .... just guessing also that this group will also found there.@Enkidu

Comment: also reps of groups don't frighten me. So again, is there a name? but since I now know it is about reps of finite grous: what is $n$? is it a number, or can it be a tableaux? respectively a weight?

Comment: I suggest you look a little bit through the List of notations given in the book! there should be at least a name!